# Retrieving the type names from Elasticsearch Index using Nest

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

This is the code that I'm using to get https://esURL/index-name/_mappings

```
client.GetMapping<object>(mapping => mapping.Index("index-name").AllTypes())
```

However, this only returns the properties of the mappings and not the names.

Is there something that I am missing with the code?

I also wanna add that I'm using Nest 2.5.0.

Comment: Do you mean, type names?

Comment: Yes, the type names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all of the type names in one or all indices in NEST 2.5.0 with

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

// just change .Index() for .AllIndices() for indices
var mappings = client.GetMapping<object>(m => m.Index("posts").AllTypes());

foreach (var index in mappings.IndexTypeMappings)
{
    foreach (var type in index.Value)
    {
        // do something with type names
        Console.WriteLine($"index: '{index.Key.Name}', type: '{type.Key.Name}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me. Just for clarification, can this be done in Nest 2.3.0? Or is it just a feature in 2.5.0?

Comment: `IndexTypeMappings` has been in NEST since 2.3.1 so cannot be done in 2.3.0. It is recommended to always update NEST to the latest version for the major version you're using i.e. if you're using Elasticsearch 2.x, then update to the latest version of NEST 2.x

Comment: Here's the commit that added it: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/commit/57cfb72f